# Solve for k when 2 lines have the same gradient

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The lines 2x-k=ky and (k+1)x=6y-3 have the same gradient. Find the possible values of k. Answer is -4 or 3 but i would rather have the working out.

Answer (score 0):

$$ 2x-k=ky$$

$$ (k+1)x=6y-3$$

Change it to this form!

$$ y=mx+c$$

$$y=\frac{2x}{k}-1$$

$$y=\frac{(k+1)x}{6}+\frac{1}{2} $$

Since their gradient is the same then

$$\frac{2}{k}=\frac{k+1}{6}$$

$$12=k^2+k$$

$$k^2+k-12=0$$

$$(k+4)(k-3)=0$$

$$k=-4 $$

$$k=3$$

Answer (score 0):

First line: $y=\frac{2}{k}x-1$.

Second line: $y=\frac{k+1}{6}x+\frac{1}{2}$.

Same gradient means: $\frac{2}{k}=\frac{k+1}{6}$.

Your turn !